# NSFileManager to search image file in folder

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsfilemanager

I am using NSFileManager to search "index.png" file. if file doesnt exist then I am trying to display default image. I am using the code below but Its not working. Am i doing something incorrect here?

```
NSString *path;
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString path1 = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:literature.localURL.path];
path = [path1 stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"index.PNG"];

    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path]){
        cell.preview = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path1];
    }
    else {
        cell.preview = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Default-HTML5.PNG"];
    }
}
```

Comment: Try printing out the path NSString - see what's in it once you've built up the path. What's in literature.localURL?

Answer (score 1):

You are setting path equal to two different things. Use a different string for one of them, for example

```
NSString *path1 = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:literature.localURL.path];
```

and keep the other the same

and make "index.PNG" "index.png". iOS is case-sensitive.

Comment: Chris. I made the changes and path1 shows the files instead of folders. Also path appends folderpath/index.png instead of searching the folder.

Answer (score 1):

```
cell.preview = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: path];
```

quote apple document :

```
imageNamed:
Returns the image object associated with the specified filename.

+ (UIImage *)imageNamed:(NSString *)name
Parameters
name
The name of the file. If this is the first time the image is being loaded, the method looks for an image with the specified name in the application’s main bundle.
```

your png not in main bundle but in the your folder

```
imageWithContentsOfFile:
Creates and returns an image object by loading the image data from the file at the specified path.
```

Comment: Thanks Guo. This makes perfect sense..:)

Comment: Guo. I have followed Chris' suggestion but the all the files still showing default image even if the index.png image exists in some folders. I have updated the code above.

Comment: @akash your "path1" is folder path? or file path? [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path] it should "path" not "path1" , if it is still not work maybe your path is wrong , make a break point at "if" to check whether it goes into the if statement

Comment: path1 is folder path. it is going to else statement. NSLog gave me path1-> folder paths and path prints out folder-path/index.png.

Comment: @akash imageWithContentsOfFile: the method need the file path , you should pass the "path"(your XXXX/XXX/XXX/index.png) to it

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23679/discussion-between-akash-and-guo-luchuan)

Answer (score 0):

```
imageNamed:
```

for images

> the method looks for an image with the specified name in the application’s main bundle.

, for documents dir, you must use

```
[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: path];
```

as `Guo Luchuan` said